# how to use fopen to open usb flash directory and then use fread to read the 512b block?

Tags: c, fopen, fread

i want to use c program to read allocation unit from USB memory card ,
so what is the path to the USB memory directory and then read all 512b 
allocation unit?
(I am using ubuntu)

Comment: To read the raw data from any device you need to open its device file in `/dev`. Note that it might require root privileges.

Comment: do you have an example?